# Drupal 6 : views_get_view_result

Tags: php, json, drupal, view

I need to retrieve the result of a view and encode it in json after. By doing this, it shows me 'Array' but not the content. Could you tell me where I'm wrong? thank you a lot!

```
function web_service_expositions($viewname, $display_id = NULL, $args = NULL) {
  $view = views_get_view('expositions_now');
  if (is_object($view)) {
    if (is_array($args)) {
      $view->set_arguments($args);
    }
    if (is_string($display_id)) {
      $view->set_display($display_id);
    }
    else {
      $view->init_display();
    }
    $view->pre_execute();
    $view->execute();
/*  print "<pre> $viewname: $display_id";
    print_r(get_class_methods($view));  */
    return $view->result;
  }
  else {
    return t('View %viewname not found.', array('%viewname' => $viewname));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing

return $view->result;

with

```
drupal_json_output($view->result);
drupal_exit();
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7